# How can I get access to ListViewItem from its child control?

Tags: c#, wpf, listviewitem

I have some `ListViewItem`s from a collection, I have created a `DataTemplate`  so that each of `ListViewItem` has a `Button` as a child control:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate_AwesomeTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Button Content="Awesome Button" Click="Awesome_Button_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="AwesomeListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="577" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="934" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Foreground="Black" Margin="10,10,0,0">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
       <GridViewColumn Header="AwesomeHeader" Width="250" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate_AwesomeTemplate}"/>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

When I click a certain `Button`, is there a way to change the `IsSelected` property of the `ListViewItem` that contains the clicked `Button`?

Comment: Change how? Select, unselect or toggle? If toggle then have you considered using `ToggleButton` instead?

Comment: @dkozl I just want to select it sir. sorry for late respon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the `IsSelected` *property* of the `ListViewItem` that contains the clicked `Button` you should use the `DataContext` to find the item like this:

```
private void Awesome_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var item = (sender as Button).DataContext;
     int index = AwesomeListView.Items.IndexOf(item);//find the index of the item that contains the clicked button
     AwesomeListView.SelectedItem = AwesomeListView.Items[index];//set the AwesomeListView's SelectedItem to item that contains the clicked button
}
```