# Select unfocusable ListViewItem by clicking

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListView` that gets populated by an ObservableCollection via Binding. Its `ListViewItem`s should have `Focusable="False"` as I don't want a `TextBox` to lose keyboard focus when clicking anything. Unfortunately, this prevents ListViewItems from being selected by clicking on them. How can I make ListViewItems selectable by clicking without changing the current focus?

I tried selecting an item in code by doing

```
myListView.SelectedIndex = i;
```

but I couldn't find a way to find the index of the clicked item. I can't use `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild()` to check for `IsMouseOver` because the data binding does not actually add controls to the visual tree.

Please don't suggest resetting the focus to the TextBox. The TextBox should not lose focus at all.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549547/how-can-i-get-access-to-listviewitem-from-its-child-control).

I added `PreviewMouseDown="OnMouseDown"` to my ListViewItem template (in my case to the `Border` element) which selects the corresponding item by doing:

```
private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (sender as Border).DataContext;
    myListView.SelectedIndex = myListView.Items.IndexOf(item);
}
```