# How to set SelectedItem to ListViewItem from its child

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, resourcedictionary

Is there an easy way to set the `SelectedItem` of my `ListView` when the `TextBox` gets the focus by <kbd>Tab</kbd> navigation?

AdditionalInformation.xaml:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding PropertieList}" Style="{DynamicResource AdditionalInfo_ListViewStyle}" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{DynamicResource AdditionalInfo_GridView_HeaderStyle}">
            <GridViewColumn Header=" Name" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{DynamicResource AdditionalInfo_Body_TextBlockStyle}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header=" Value"  >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" IsEnabled="{Binding AllowValueChanging}" MinWidth="300" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

ResourceDictionary

```
<Style x:Key="AdditionalInfo_ListViewStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:ResourceKeys.ListView_L2_Background_Body_BackgroundBrush}}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="14,0,14,0" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="Continue" />
    
    <!--Row style-->
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:ResourceKeys.ListView_L2_Background_Body_BackgroundBrush}}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:ResourceKeys.ListView_L2_Background_Body_BackgroundBrush_Hover}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:ResourceKeys.ListView_L2_Background_Body_BackgroundBrush_Hover}}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:ResourceKeys.ListView_L2_Background_Body_BackgroundBrush_IsSelected}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:ResourceKeys.ListView_L2_Background_Body_BackgroundBrush_IsSelected}}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!--Header-->
<Style x:Key="AdditionalInfo_GridView_HeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:ResourceKeys.ListView_L2_Background_Header_ForegrounddBrush_enabled}}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:ResourceKeys.ListView_L2_Background_Header_BackgroundBrush}}" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="AdditionalInfo_Body_TextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:ResourceKeys.ListView_L2_Background_Body_ForegrounddBrush_enabled}}" />
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:ResourceKeys.ListView_L2_Background_Body_ForegrounddBrush_disabled}}" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

As shown here [How can I get access to ListViewItem from its child control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549547/how-can-i-get-access-to-listviewitem-from-its-child-control) it would be possible to set the `SelectedItem` by using the code-behind but I do not like to use the code-behind for this *simple* task.

AdditionalInformation.xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="AdditionalInfoListView" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding PropertieList}" Style="{DynamicResource AdditionalInfo_ListViewStyle}" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{DynamicResource AdditionalInfo_GridView_HeaderStyle}">
            <GridViewColumn Header=" Name" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{DynamicResource AdditionalInfo_Body_TextBlockStyle}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header=" Value"  >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" IsEnabled="{Binding AllowValueChanging}" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" MinWidth="300" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

AdditionalInformation.xaml.cs

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (sender as TextBox).DataContext;
    int index = AdditionalInfoListView.Items.IndexOf(item);
    AdditionalInfoListView.SelectedItem = AdditionalInfoListView.Items[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Trigger` to set the `IsSelected` state depending on `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` in your item container style. Whenever you focus a `TextBox`, it will focus the row, too.

```
<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
   <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
</Trigger>
```

Here is the trigger merged with your items container style. Please note that the `SelectedItem` will only be set as long as your `TextBox` is focused, since you set the `Focusable` to `False` in your style. When the focus is moved, e.g. clicking a button, the `SelectedItem` will be reset to `null`. If you remove the focusable setter, the trigger will still work, the row stays focused and the `SelectedItem` will be kept even when clicking a button.

```
<Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:ResourceKeys.ListView_L2_Background_Body_BackgroundBrush}}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:ResourceKeys.ListView_L2_Background_Body_BackgroundBrush_Hover}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:ResourceKeys.ListView_L2_Background_Body_BackgroundBrush_Hover}}"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:ResourceKeys.ListView_L2_Background_Body_BackgroundBrush_IsSelected}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:ResourceKeys.ListView_L2_Background_Body_BackgroundBrush_IsSelected}}"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for - THANKS!!